# Is there a way for finding the vertices of the pixel in the HEALPix C library?

Tags: c, idl, healpy

There is a nice funcion in the IDL version of HEALPix (pix2vec_nest) that can return a vector(n,3,4) with the coordinates of vertices of the pixel(s).
The same funcion in the C version don't do the same, and it looks you can know just the coordinates od the center of the pixel. There is a way to calculate the coordinates of the vertices?

The geometry and the mathematics of this thing is a bit hard for me for writing a generator of HEALPix pixelzation. I tried to understand the IDL code in order to add the funtionality to the C library but it looks very messy with indecipherable varable names.

```
function sub_compute_vertices, z, z_nv, z_sv, phi, phi_nv, phi_sv, hdelta_phi

np = n_elements(z)
vertex = dblarr(np, 3, 4)

sth = SQRT((1.0d0-z)*(1.0d0+z))

sth_nv = sqrt((1.0d0-z_nv)*(1.0d0+z_nv))
vertex[*,*,0] = [[sth_nv*cos(phi_nv)],[sth_nv*sin(phi_nv)],[z_nv]] ; north vertex

phi_wv = phi - hdelta_phi
vertex[*,*,1] = [[sth*cos(phi_wv)],[sth*sin(phi_wv)],[z]] ; west vertex

sth_sv = sqrt((1.0d0-z_sv)*(1.0d0+z_sv))
vertex[*,*,2] = [[sth_sv*cos(phi_sv)],[sth_sv*sin(phi_sv)],[z_sv]] ; south vertex

phi_ev = phi + hdelta_phi
vertex[*,*,3] = [[sth*cos(phi_ev)],[sth*sin(phi_ev)],[z]] ; east vertex


return, vertex
```

this code looks simple in a way, but there is other code in the file "Healpix_3.50\src\idl\toolkitpix2vec_nest.pro" that calls this function with all those parameters.. if you have and idea.. thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about healpy but it is unclear what you mean by "the vertices of a pixel". A pixel is a single point, or do you mean an object which is projected as a single pixel?

Comment: Oh it isn't! : ) On your screen pixels are square and have a side of several micrometers! In a cosmological spherical map you have also pixels. And you want they have the same area (and other  features) so they invented the HEALPix pixelization. Those pixels are diamond-like shaped, they have a centre and boundaries too! Some times you need to know where exactly a pixel starts and finishes.

Comment: So my second statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

In the C library there isn't such function. You can find it in the Java version, in the IDL version and in the C++ version of the HEALPix library version 3.50.
I've used the C++ version and it works very well. I've found hard to translate the code to C due the complexity of the algorithm.